# How to ignore @Where clause in a native query?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a native query between two tables, first and second.

The native query is made of the first entity with an inner join of the second where the second column `exists` has to be = 1, however in the representation of the second table there is the `@Where` clause that defines a fixed value of = 0 whenever that table is "accessed".

My difficulty is that even if I put in my native query that I want my result to be based on `exist = 1` the relationship query made "automatically" by JPA sets the value to 0.

I would like this `@Where(exist = 0)` clause described in `SecondTable` to be ignored in my native query.

Has can I achieve this?

Sorry about my English! :)

Here is the example code:

```
public class FirstTable  {

  private Long id;

  @OneToOne()
  @JoinColumn(name = "secondTable")
  private SecondTable secondTable;

  // another columns...........



@Where(clause = "EXIST = 0")
public class SecondTable  {

  private Long id;

  // another columns...........


  @Query(value = "select * from FirstTable FT 
                  inner join SecondTable ST  
                  on FT.secondTable=ST.id
                  where ST.EXIST = 1", nativeQuery = true)
  List<FirstTable> searchFistTable();   
  
  // ....
```

Comment: The code you added has some issues. You cannot have a method like this `List<FirstTable> searchFistTable();` inside a class. Methods with no body can be declared in interfaces. Also @Query annotation looks like the one from Spring Data and is usually used inside Spring Repositories which are usually interfaces.

Comment: friend, I know the codido has some issues. He is just an example to illustrate the problem. I have an entity (firstEntity) that makes a join with another entity (SecondEntity) that through hibernate will make a select on this secontEntity automatically inserting exist = what is the @where clause fixed in secondentity ... understand?

Comment: You can't. The native query you are using is retrieving the FirstTable instances that match the selection query you specified, but forces the provider to still use its mappings to bring in referenced objects - and that means a separate query for the SecondTable objects. If you want SecondTable instances where exists=1, query on those directly instead.

Comment: Tks for your answer, but
I solved by putting a second table as lazy